# How to create security filter for Spark UI in Spark on YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

**Environment**:
AWS EMR, yarn cluster.

**Description**:
I am trying to use a java filter to protect the access to spark ui, this by using the property spark.ui.filters; the problem is that when spark is running on yarn mode, that property is being allways overriden by hadoop with the filter org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter:

```
spark.ui.filters: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
```

and this two parameters are being passed automatically by haddoop

```
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS: ip-x-x-x-226.eu-west-1.compute.internal

spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES: http://ip-x-x-x-226.eu-west-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx
```

Any suggestion of how to add a java security filter so hadoop does not override it, or maybe how to configure the security from hadoop side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solved by using the property hadoop.http.authentication.type to
specify a custom Java Handler objects that contains the authentication
logic. This class only has to implement the
interface org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationHandler.
See:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html